# Python Sklearn multi-linear Regression for probabilities - normalize coefficients to 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, probability

The question is simple. I have three equations: OmegaMIX = beta1*Omega1+beta2*Omega2 and I want to find the best coefficients by the linear regression, where intercept is 0. I have obtained the code, but the beta1 and beta2 are probabilities, so it must be beta1+beta2 = 1, which is not the case. How can this be set?
This is the existing code:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
inputfilename = 'JO.csv' #input
df = pd.read_csv(inputfilename)
x = df.drop('OmegaMIX',axis=1) #Reference temperature
y = df['OmegaMIX'] #Multiparametric LIRs
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression(positive=True,fit_intercept=False)
regr.fit(x, y)
print('\u03B21 = ', regr.coef_[0])
print('\u03B22 = ', regr.coef_[1])
print("Quality = ", regr.score(x, y, sample_weight=None))
```

and the output is:

```
β1 =  0.33995522604783796
β2 =  0.5794270911721245
Quality =  0.9995968335914979
```

The input file is:

```
OmegaMIX,Omega1,Omega2
2.70,4.43,2.09
1.84,3.00,1.37
0.50,1.19,0.17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done on sklearn. I would rather use CVXPY as you can control the constraints.

Here's an example :

```py
import pandas as pd
import cvxpy as cp

df = pd.read_csv('JO.csv')

# Setting out matrix X and our vector y, cvxpy needs them to be numpy arrays
X = df.drop('OmegaMIX', axis=1).values
y = df['OmegaMIX'].values

# Defining the variables of the problem
beta1 = cp.Variable()
beta2 = cp.Variable()

# setting the constraints
constraints = [beta1 >= 0, beta2 >= 0, beta1 + beta2 == 1]

# Defining the linear regression problem
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.sum_squares(X[:, 0] * beta1 + X[:, 1] * beta2 - y))

# Solving the probelem
problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
problem.solve()

# printing the betas
print('\u03B21 =', beta1.value)
print('\u03B22 =', beta2.value)
print('\u03B21 + \u03B22 =', (beta1.value + beta2.value))
print("Quality =", problem.value)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the perfect answer, and it did solve this issue. I will now try to scale it up to N variables.